# Animation when remove UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have collection view, and have logic to delete cells from it. However, when cell is removed, next cell is appeared instantly on deleted cell place. Is there a way to add animation for deletion, for example, for 0.5 sec change opaque of cell, or something similar? There is a method i use for delete cell:

```
-(void)aMethod:(UIButton*)sender{
    [self.viewModel deleteAt:[sender tag]];
    [self.myCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: What about using `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:` instead of reloading your whole collection view? For your animation, you can take a look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690831/uicollectionview-animations-insert-delete-items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use:

```
 [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
                            [self.myCollectionView reloadData];
                        }];
```