# UICollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths with animation crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have UICollectionView. I want to delete a item with animation. So I have used the below code.

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15f animations:^{
    [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
    }];
```

Sometimes it crashes and saying that

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException Invalid update:
>   invalid number of items in section 0. The number of items contained in
>   an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number
>   of items contained in that section before the update (5), plus or
>   minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0
>   inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into
>   or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Can somebody help me out on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to delete the item also from the collection view data source.

Comment: Check numberOfCelInSection, I thing you didn't remove and recount number of object.

Comment: Hope this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690831/uicollectionview-animations-insert-delete-items) helps you