# Simple collectionView animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview

How can i animate the loading of cells into a collectionview.

Ive been playing with the following code but it only animates cells that are off screen when i scroll.

How to animate the all the cells not the screen to start?

```
    let finalFrame: CGRect = cell.frame
        cell.frame = CGRect(x: finalFrame.origin.x - 1000, y: -500, width: 0, height: 0)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        cell.frame = finalFrame
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618045-performbatchupdates)

And inside the `performBatchUpdates` block:

**For** `items`:

Insert: [insertItems(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618097-insertitemsatindexpaths)

Delete: [deleteItems(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618060-deleteitemsatindexpaths?language=objc)

Move/Reorder: [moveItem(at:to:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618059-moveitematindexpath?language=objc)

**For** `sections`:

Insert: [insertSections(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618090-insertsections)

Delete: [deleteSections(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618102-deletesections)

Move/Reorder: [moveItem(at:to:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618059-moveitem)

**If you want to further customize your animations:**

1: [Check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690831/uicollectionview-animations-insert-delete-items)

2: [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCAfeTqsE_Y&ab_channel=JaredDavidson)

3: [Github Project](https://github.com/seedante/CollectionViewAnimation)

4: [Alternative UIStackView for Swift 3 Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRwZ3udgkFk&ab_channel=devslopes)