# Remove UICollectionView cells on edit button

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using a UICollectionView to retrieve images and labels stored in the Cloud database Parse.

I now need an option that will let me delete a certain image and its corresponding label.

I am looking for something such as the typical iPhone "Edit" button on the top right hand corner which displays a swipe animation with a delete button next to the cell. I'm aware that such a thing can be done on a UITableView through

```
[[self tableView] setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

but I can't seem to find the equivalent for a UICollectionView anywhere.

Any help appreciated, even if it doesn't deal with the deletion from Parse itself, just the editing style on the collection view would be ideal.

Here is how I populate my cells:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self retrieveSelectedImages];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [imageFilesArray count];
}


-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"myRoomsCell";
MyRoomsCell *cell = (MyRoomsCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

PFObject *imageObject = [imageFilesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
PFFile *imageFile = [imageObject objectForKey:@"imageFile"];

cell.loadingSpinner.hidden = NO; //show loading spinner to indicate work is happening until the image loads
[cell.loadingSpinner startAnimating];

// UILabel *label = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:5];
cell.label.text= [imageObject objectForKey:@"roomLabel"]; //set room label as the label stored on parse previously inserted by the user

cell.label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18];
cell.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;


[imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    if (!error) {
        cell.parseImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        [cell.loadingSpinner stopAnimating];
        cell.loadingSpinner.hidden = YES;
    }
}];

return cell;
}

-(void) retrieveSelectedImages
{
//parse query where we search the favorites array column and return any entry where the array contains the logged in user objectid
PFQuery *getFavorites = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"collectionViewData"];
[getFavorites whereKey:@"selectedImage" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];

[getFavorites findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error)
    {
        imageFilesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        [roomsCollection reloadData];
    }
}];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this answer with plenty of code for you to try out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16190291/1914567

Basically, there is no Apple-provided way to do this.

There are also some really nice libraries. My personal favorite is [DraggableCollectionView](https://github.com/lukescott/DraggableCollectionView), and also check out [LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout](https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout).

Answer (score -3):

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [[Singleton sharedSingleton].selectedProfileArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [selectCollectionView reloadData];
}
```