# What is the most common way to delete cells from a UICollectionView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

What is the most common way to delete cells from a `UICollectionView`?

In a `UITableView` I use the `editActionsForRowAt` or `editingStyle` methods to delete rows, does `UIControllerView` has something similar or you need to implement your own deleting method?

What I have is a `UICollectionView` with a lot of photos where each cell/photo is attached to a segue which takes you to a larger version of the photo.

The easiest way I could be to do it in the `didSelectItemAt` method but in my case that is not an option since as soon as a photo is tapped it segues to the other viewController (larger image).

What would be the best way to add a deleting functionality in a situation like the one I'm describing above?

The following threads show how to delete using the `didSelectItemAt`.

[How to add a delete button to Collection View Cell in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610316/how-to-add-a-delete-button-to-collection-view-cell-in-swift)
[How to delete item from collection view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490358/how-to-delete-item-from-collection-view)

### CODE

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return fruits.count
}
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "fruitCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! fruitCollectionViewCell

    cell.labelFruitName.text = fruits[indexPath.row].fruitName
    return cell
}
```

### App Diagram

[image]

Comment: I believe this has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28748393/remove-uicollectionview-cells-on-edit-button

Comment: Try implement the way iOS apps are deleted from main menu ie. long clicking and starting edit mode and then on selection delete the cell.

Comment: Thanks you all for your suggestions, I will try to implement my own deleting method, may be by adding a delete-button to each image when an EDIT button is tapped and then assign a tag to each button to keep track of which images was tapped. Thanks